# Установка DBI, DBD::Oracle на Oracle Linux

Tags: active-perl

Есть ОС `Oracle Linux 7.6`, БД `Oracle 11.2.0.4`, 2 пользователя в системе: `orcl` и `root`.
Моя машина крутится на `virtual box`. Я ее запускаю и с ОС своего ПК подключаюсь к ней по `SSH`.(все попытки проводятся на клонах машины).

> Требуется выгрузить данные из БД в браузере

Клиент заходит по адресу, например, `192.168.0.1/`, выбирает нужный отчет, вводит дату и жмет кнопочку ПОКАЗАТЬ.
В это время запускается `Perl` скрипт, подключается к БД и выводит результат в браузере.

---

Но возникает ошибка:

```
install driver DBD::Oracle failed can't locate Oracle.so for libclntsh.so.11.1.
```

Пробовал разные варианты, ошибка остаётся.

---

***Мои действия:***

1. Проверил, что `sqlplus` работает: `sqlplus system/123456@test; select * from m;` и `Apache` `192.168.56.101/`
2. Установка `cpan` (под `root`) `yum -y install cpan`
3. Настройка `httpd.conf`. *Тут только есть один нюанс: от какого пользователя запускать сервис `Apache`. По умолчанию пользователь и группа `apache` Пробовал менять на `orcl` или `root` и `Apache` не перезагружается (`systemctl restart httpd`)*
4. Установка модулей (все под юзером `orcl`):

Дал полные права `0777` на папку `/usr`, иначе модули не ставятся:

```
cpan
install DBI
get DBD::Oracle
cd /home/orcl/.cpan/build/DBD-....
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
```

*(И тут почти у всех тестов предупреждение `unable to connect to oracle`)*
Я написал:

```
export ORACLE_USERID=system/123456@test
make test
```

*(И тут все тесты ОК кроме одного `t/plsql25t`)*

```
make install
```

Comment: Перл использовал как предустановленный, так и ставил в отдельный каталог. Если начинаю менять oracle_home = пропадает sqlplus, если меняю LD_LIBRARY, то и в cmd получаю уже ошибку как в апаче. Также пробовал ставить instantclient.Вот этот файлик sh.s0.11.1 находится в oracle_home/lib.Если его ручками положить в /usr/lib64, то уже ошибка OciEnvNlsCreate, которая совсем не лечится.

Comment: Заметил, что перлу в командной строке все равно, что написано в первой строке скрипта (!#/usr/bin/perl).А вот для апача нет, если начинаю ее менять, то одна из трех ошибок в логе: no such file/ permission denied/ exec format error

Answer (score 0):

Получилось самостоятельно решить вопрос "Установка Apache+Perl в локальный каталог".

Каталог нужен потому, что все устанавливается под юзером, у которого нет прав на установку в каталог по умолчанию /usr/lib64.

1. установка Apache (под root)

   ```
   $ rpm -Uvh httpd-2.4.6-89.0.1.el7_6.x86_64.rpm
   ```
2. установка Perl (под oracle)

   ```
   cd
   tar -zxvf perl-5.12.2.tar.gz
   cd perl-5.12.2
   ./Configure -des -Dprefix=/u01/localperl
   make test
   make install
   ```
3. Установка DBI (под oracle)

   ```
   cd
   cd $HOME/perlbuilds
   tar -zxvf DBI-1.615.tar.gz
   cd DBI-1.615
   /u01/localperl/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/u01/localperl
   make
   make test
   make install
   ```
4. Качаем с сайта oracle instantclient. Так как моя БД работает на версии 12.1, то ее и скачал:

   - basic+sqlplus+sdk
   - Извлекаем все 3 архива в одну папку (instantclient_12_1).
   - Копируем папку instantclient_12_1 в /u01/localperl/lib.
   - Далее устанавливаем переменную export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/localperl/lib/instantclient_12_1
5. (под oracle)Установка DBD::Oracle

   ```
   cd ~/perlbuilds
   tar -zxvf DBD-Oracle-1.26.tar.gz
   cd DBD-Oracle-1.26
   /u01/localperl/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/u01/localperl
   make
   make install
   ```

Готово.
Вот проверочный скрипт начало:

```
#!/u01/localperl/bin/perl –w
```